# tcp packet loss occurs occasionally when use dpdk19.11 i40e NIC

Tags: dpdk

I am using XL710 i40e NIC on dpdk19.11. I found that the NIC occasionally lost packets when I enabled the TSO feature.

The detailed information is as follow:
https://github.com/JiangHeng12138/dpdk-issue/issues/1

I gussed lost packet is caused by i40e NIC dirver, but I dont know how to debug i40e driver code, could you please provide me an effective way.

Comment: can you please share the pmd stats and nic stats (dpdk-procinfo tool for stats and xstats). Please also share DPDK NIC is PF or VF with details about the firmware used. Are you flashing with any special DDP on x710 too?

Comment: how to check dpdk NIC is PF or VF? "dpdk-devbin -s" command output: 0000:05:00.1 'Ethernet Controller XL710 for 40GbE QSFP+ 1583' drv=vfio-pci unused=i40e,igb_uio; is it PF?      I didn't flash special DDP

Comment: J.Heng, based on the PCIe id `0000:05:00.1` it appears to be PF. can you please share NIC stats while you see the problem to identify if its PMD or HW packet drop too?

Comment: dpdk-proinfo stats: https://github.com/JiangHeng12138/dpdk-issue/issues/1#issuecomment-1285010980 ; https://github.com/JiangHeng12138/dpdk-issue/issues/1#issuecomment-1285011556; it seems no drop packets?

Comment: The number of sent packets measured by the dpdk-procinfo is the same as that measured by the upper-layer app. However, the tcpdump detects packet loss.

Comment: as per the stats shared, there is no packet dropped at the NIC and no packet dropped at sw PMD. But your claim is `tcpdump` shows the packet drop. I need to check and understand more will check the github link. Right now I am not convinced, if there is switch or router in between and it drops packets before the DPDK NIC, there is no magic way to recreate them at the DPDK side.

Comment: which item indicates that NIC does not discard data?     my two machines are directly connected, no router. data loss is almost impossible.

Comment: does "tx_good_packets" indicate the data sent by NIC in i40e? I just consulted the colleague of dpdk hns3 driver. He said that "tx_good_packets" indicates only the amount of data transmitted to the driver, but not the number of packets actually sent by the NIC. hns3 have additional item starting with mac_ prefix, indicates the data actualy sent form NIC.

Comment: here is how I interpret the tx data, for whatever successful tx_burst to DMA descriptor is done all are transmitted from the NIC. But if `tx_burst` is not successful and application logic does not retry and does `mbuf_free` this will not be accounted and packet will be dropped. To debug this one needs `app statistics` and I always recommend to keep `TX descriptor to least 1024`

Comment: Sorry, not clear what you mean....  If the number of sent packets counted by the app is the same as the number of sent packets counted by the tx_good_packets, does that mean that no packet is lost?

Comment: yes if the number of packets tried to be sent (that is nb_pkts in rte_eth_tx_burst) is to equal to actual return of tx_burst that is equal to `dpdk-procinfo stats`. Then problem is in the application logic not generating the `packet (in your case TCP-ACK)` sufficently.

Comment: If so, I suspect that packet loss may be caused by the peer. Is there any command on the i40e NIC to measure packet loss?   The peer server is in kernel mode and not used dpdk.

Comment: "ethtool -s eth0" command can statistic packet lost. Packets are lost at the peer...

Comment: when one binds the NIC to DPDK the `kernel netlink device will be absent`. Hence one can not use `ethtool -S on PF or VF physical NIC in DPDK`. With respect to the peer dropping the packets, means the Peer system were not able to process the packet due to checksum error, frame error, or high load on peer system.

Comment: But `this is not dpdk or dpdk-nic issue if it is peer dropping the packet`. right? So can you please re-phrase your question as it was suggesting it is dpdk-nic and dpdk 19.11 dropping the packets?

Comment: today, I try the peer is dpdk-nic, it is also lost data: ./dpdk-procinfo  -- --xstats | grep errors output : rx_missed_errors: 374 , Does this value indicate packet loss on the dpdk NIC or SW PMD?  I guess some buffer overflows, or the app reads too slowly.  Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: In short, no packet loss occurs at the send client...... By the way, are you the maintainer of dpdk? It seems that you answer all the dpdk questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: the stats shared in https://github.com/JiangHeng12138/dpdk-issue/issues/1, did not have `rx-missed-errors`. But if you are seeing the error in the new run, this means the you are processing packets more than what Current CPU can handle. So either you will need to increase CPU frequency, or use additional cores to distribute the traffic.

Comment: with respect to the maintainer role, No I am not a maintainer for DPDK or DPDK PMD. But have contributed to DPDK, and still help and contribute people using DPDK library from debug, optimization, solutions, and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the problem statement `tcp packet loss occurs occasionally when use dpdk19.11 i40e NIC`, one needs to isolate the issue whether is it is client (peer system) or server (dpdk DUT) which leads to packet loss. So to debug the issue at DPDK server side, one needs to evaluate both RX and TX issues. DPDK tool `dpdk-procinfo` can retrieve port statistics, which can be used for the analysis of the issue.

Diagnose the issue:

1. Run the application (dpdk primary) to reproduce the issue in terminal-1.
2. In terminal-2, run the command `dpdk-procinfo -- --stats`. refer [link](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/tools/proc_info.html) for more details
3. Check `RX-errors` counter, ***this will show if the packets which were faulty were dropped at PMD level***.
4. Check `RX-nombuf` counter, ***this will show if the packets from NIC were not able to be DMA to DDR memory on the HOST***.
5. Check `TX-errors` counter, ***this will show if the copy of packet descriptor (DMA descriptors) to NIC had been faulty or not***.
6. Also check the HW nic statistics with `dpdk-procinfo -- --xstats` for ***any error or drop counter updates***.

[sample of the capture of stats and xstats counters on the desired nic](https://github.com/JiangHeng12138/dpdk-issue/issues/1#issuecomment-1285011556)

Note:

1. "tx_good_packets" means the number of packets sent by the dpdk NIC.  if the number of packets tried to be sent is equal to "tx_good_packets", there is no packet dropped at the sent client.
2. "rx-missed-errors" means packets loss at the receiver; this means you are processing packets more than what the Current CPU can handle. So either you will need to increase CPU frequency, or use additional cores to distribute the traffic.

***If none of these counters is updated or errors are found, then the issue is at the peer (client non-dpdk) side.***

Comment: if "rx-missed-errors" is not 0, you can set larger RX descriptor to avoid